# Переход на на другое активити из фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

У меня есть главное активити (MainActivity) и в нем находится фрагмент, как из кода этого фрагмента перейти на новое активити? Делаю вот так -

Часть кода фрагмента:

```
 MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
 mainActivity.goToTestInfoProfile();
```

Часть кода MainActivity:

```
public void goToTestInfoProfile(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestInfoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Но в итоге вылезает NullPointerException. Попытался перейти на другое активити на прямую из фрагмента, но также NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в файл `AndroidManifest` строку с вашим `acitivty` на который вы хотите чтобы совершался `intent`:

```
...</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".TestInfoActivity"
</activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

И далее, в нужном вам методе вызывайте `intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TestInfoActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

В фрагменте напиши:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TestInfoActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Не получилось, та же ошибка

Comment: `TestInfoActivity` у вас прописан в манифесте?

Answer (score 1):

Не правильно создавать новый экземпляр MainActivity, чтобы стартовать другое активити.

Нужно вызывать метод startActivity у уже существующего контекста. 
Это можно сделать прямо во фрагменте.